# Semantic UI Dropdown Needs 2 Clicks to Fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, reactjs, semantic-ui

I am using a Semantic UI dropdown in this [project](http://mealette.herokuapp.com) along with ReactJS. The first time you click on the dropdown menu (on the top right of the page) nothing happens; on the second click, the dropdown menu appears as intended. I think this might have to do with the tabindex attribute. When I inspect the element on the first click, it sets it to 0 and on the second click it sets it to -1. However, setting those manually has no effect. Or, maybe it's a jQuery vs Semantic UI conflict?

Here is the code for the React component:

```
var Menu = React.createClass({

showDropdown: function(){
  $('.dropdown')
    .dropdown({
      transition: 'drop'
    });
},

render: function(){
    return(
        <div>
            <div className="ui red inverted menu">
              <div className="header item">Mealette</div>
              <div className="right menu">

                <div onClick={this.showDropdown} className="ui dropdown">
                  <div className="item header">
                    <i className="sidebar icon"></i>
                  </div>

                  <div className="ui menu menu-dropdown">
                    <div className="item">
                      <MoreRestaurantsFilter />
                    </div>
                    <div className="item">
                      <ChangeLocationLink>Change Location</ChangeLocationLink>
                    </div>
                    <div className="">
                      <CategoryFilter />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    )
}

});
```

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you check your dev tools console, is there an error message after the first click?

Comment: no errors are firing in the console. were you able to see the link to the project? http://mealette.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I think is happening:

1. You click the menu and it calls `showDropdown`.
2. In `showDropdown`, the jQuery dropdown handling is set up, then control returns to the main application without triggering the dropdown itself.
3. You click again, and jQuery actually handles the event this time (and may reattach itself, leading to duplicate event listeners and a memory leak over time).

There are a couple ways you could attack this problem. The naive solution would probably be to call the Semantic UI dropdown control's `show` method (or whatever it's called), e.g.

```
showDropdown: function() {
  $('.dropdown').dropdown({
    transition: 'drop'
  });

  // not sure if this is right, but it's roughly how Bootstrap works
  $('.dropdown').dropdown('show')
}
```

A slight step up would probably be to use React `refs` instead of class names with the above approach. You could also check to see if the dropdown has already been attached before re-attaching it to avoid memory leaks.

The most idiomatic React solution would probably be to set up the jQuery behavior in `componentDidMount`, then remove it (if applicable for Semantic UI) in `componentWillUnmount`, e.g.

```
componentDidMount() {
  $('.dropdown').dropdown({
    transition: 'drop'
  })
}
```

That way, jQuery manages the lifecycle of your dropdown for the entire lifecycle of the component, and you don't even need the `showDropdown` method anymore.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Happy to update this answer with correct Semantic UI commands (`destroy`? `unbind`?) if anyone happens to know them!

Comment: Thanks so much Kyle! Your suggestion of using componentDidMount worked great. We removed the showDropdown function and the onClick handler from the menu component. It seemed to be overriding or conflicting with Semantic UI's dropdown functionality.

Comment: Keep this pattern in mind anytime you're using jQuery-style libs with React. I have a Select2 component that works like this, for example. Glad it worked out!